# Can I run the Tridion 2013 SP1 Content Porter client on a machine with IE 8?

Tags: content-porter-2013

I would like to run Content Porter 2013 sp1 on a client PC that only has IE 8 installed (+ Chrome and Firefox).

Is it possible to download the Content Porter client files from another machine to my machine and run from there?

Comment: What did you try? I'd imagine that you could either bypass the browser check of the CME -- or just download the application by going directly to the URL.

Comment: Or use Chrome with the Click-Once plug-in...

Comment: Yes, tried to bypass (with no luck).  Did not try the direct URL or Chrome Click-Once.

Comment: you should be able to install it using the files.  Its located at %TridionInstall%\Content Porter\ImportExportService\Client\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I know this is not supported, but it will work just fine.

You can go to folder with ContentPorter installation package on the server, and copy all the files (I think with .deploy) extension. Put it on your client, remove .deploy extension and you are good to go.